# How to group 2 buttons with form in bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: bootstrap-4

When I try `class="btn-group"` the buttons aren't joined anymore. They are separate.

[image: btn-group]

```
<div class="btn-toolbar justify-content-between">
    <form action="{{ route('orders.destroy', ['id' => $order->id]) }}" method="post">
        {{ method_field('UPDATE') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="btn-group-sm">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ok</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form action="{{ route('orders.destroy', ['id' => $order->id]) }}" method="post">
        {{ method_field('UPDATE') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="btn-group-sm">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">del</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to create group buttons like this example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/button-group/

And boostrap 4 btn-group not working

Comment: Why do you need 2 forms by the way? It seems like they have the same action.

Answer (score 0):

Both button elements have to exist within the same tag

consider the following

```
<div class="btn-toolbar justify-content-between">
    <form action="{{ route('orders.destroy', ['id' => $order->id]) }}" method="post">
        {{ method_field('UPDATE') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="btn-group-sm">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ok</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">del</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have 2 form and a form has a submit button. I want make two forms that it btn-group

Comment: why do you have 2 forms? use one.